# PDO statements not working on a live host

Tags: php, pdo

PDO statements work on localhost but fail to work on a live host. here is an example that works fine on localhost but rowCount() always returns 0 on a live host. someone please help me.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE email = :email AND password = :password");
        $stmt->execute(array(
            ':email' => $uemail,
            ':password' => $pass
        ));
        $count = $stmt->rowCount();
```

Comment: add `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened. Plus, Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: check whether your live host support PDO

Answer (score 1):

**PDOStatement::rowCount**

> PDOStatement::rowCount() returns the number of rows affected by a DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement.

That does not work for `SELECT`, ironic but true :)

**Workaround:**

> For most databases, PDOStatement::rowCount() does not return the number of rows affected by a SELECT statement. Instead, use PDO::query() to issue a SELECT COUNT(*) statement with the same predicates as your intended SELECT statement, then use PDOStatement::fetchColumn() to retrieve the number of rows that will be returned. Your application can then perform the correct action.

Should not even work on localhost. You're interpreting the result incorrectly on localhost.

**[Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)**

Comment: Note to self: *"`rowCount()` does not work with `SELECT`, `rowCount()` does not work with `SELECT`,`rowCount()` does not work with `SELECT`"* - Got it.