# Count does not work when I rewrote my code with PDO

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

I can't get my count to work once I changed from mysql to pdo. I am not sure what to do.

```
<tr>
    <td style="width: 125px">
        <a href="SystemsTechsPages/xgrh/xgrhCompleted1.php" target="_top">xgrh</a>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 125px" align="center">
        <a href="SystemsTechsPages/xgrh/xgrhCompleted1.php" target="_top">
        <?php 

        $stmt = $db->prepare("
            SELECT COUNT(*) FROM WHERE requests status='Completed' AND compDT=Curdate() AND compUser='xgrh'
        ");  
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { 
            echo $row['COUNT(*)'];  
        }  
        ?>
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Do `SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM your_table` then do `echo $row['count'];` your table is missing btw.

Comment: I messed up forgot to put the table name in after I changed it from MySQL to PDO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change your query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS rows_cnt FROM table WHERE  status='Completed' AND compDT=Curdate() AND compUser='xgrh'
```

Then:

And use it like this:

```
$stmt->execute();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{ 
   echo $row['rows_cnt'];  
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First off, make sure to get the query right:

Its missing a table name

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (what happened here? no table name)

WHERE status='Completed' 
AND compDT=Curdate() 
AND compUser = 'xgrh'
```

Secondly, you could just use an alias to better access the column name instead:

```
<?php 
// prepare
$stmt = $db->prepare("
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM table_name 
    WHERE status='Completed' 
    AND compDT = Curdate() 
    AND compUser = 'xgrh'
");
$stmt->execute(); // execute
$result = $stmt->fetch_assoc(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$count = $result['total'];
echo $count;

?>
```

Comment: LOL! `(what happened here? no table name)` good catch. I won't put in an answer, too many already. +1 I did put in a comment though.

Comment: @Fred-ii- actually while i was scrolling, my eyes went big, WTF is that!?  lol :D

Comment: Your `(what happened here? no table name)` caught my eye which is when I edited my comment under OP's question. I too did a double take. Great, now I've a whiplash lol

Comment: Oops I had table name in I forgot to add it when I changed out the MySQL . Thanks for all the help I'm starting to understand Pdo I will give it a try and mark Answere correct tomorrow

Answer (score 2):

You should call `$stmt->execute()` before fetching. Prepared STMT is not sent to server, you should send it using execute.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the row count in PDO like so:

```
$count = $stmt->rowCount();
```

Comment: `PDOStatement::rowCount() returns the number of rows affected by the last DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement executed by the corresponding PDOStatement object.`

I don't see any of this in query.

Comment: @CappY Was about to say the same thing.

Comment: @CappY Hmmm, I actually did not know that. I use this all the time...I just read the caveat which is `...SELECT statement, some databases may return the number of rows returned by that statement. However, this behaviour is not guaranteed for all databases and should not be relied on for portable applications.` I've only used one host where I work a that rule luckily seems to apply....but I better rethink that due to the "may or may not work" notice.

Comment: @Rasclatt Don't feel bad and you're not alone. I learned this last week myself lol

Comment: @Fred-ii- Holy cow I seriously use this everywhere! That just added a crap-load of work for me to revise!! Thanks a lot!!! :D

Comment: You're welcome @Rasclatt I'm trying to remember that link on Stack where I discovered it. If I could remember the person's name who answered it, then I could easily find it.

Comment: Here is the full Statement from php.net:

PDOStatement::rowCount() returns the number of rows affected by the last DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement executed by the corresponding PDOStatement object.

If the last SQL statement executed by the associated PDOStatement was a SELECT statement, some databases may return the number of rows returned by that statement. However, this behaviour is not guaranteed for all databases and should not be relied on for portable applications. 

So rowCount can return the count but its not guaranteed that it will always give the result.

Comment: @Rasclatt Found it. It was yesterday that I learned this, not last week. Where has my mind gone? Here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26750658/ - I even placed a "Note to self" comment under it lol